# What does the title "Aldnoah.Zero" mean?

Tags: aldnoah-zero

I recently watched "Aldnoah.Zero" and started with "Aldnoah.Zero (2015)". I was wondering about one of the main elements in this anime.

> **Aldnoah** is something that was found on Mars ("Vers" as it's called by the Martians) and is something old from an ancient civilization no one knows much about. They power up their "weapon systems" (mechs) with this thing too.

**What is Aldnoah really?** Is it some sort of stone, or some sort of energy? If it were just energy, they wouldn't have so advanced weapon systems, or not?

Where does the "Zero" in the name come from?

Comment: The physical nature of Aldnoah isn't touched on in the show or in any of the side materials I've read. To be clear, though, Aldnoah-the-power-source (what the royal family has direct control over) seems to be a distinct thing from Aldnoah-the-hyper-advanced-technology (the cataphracts, the Deucalion, the Landing Castles, etc.). It just so happens that the precursor Martian civilization had both of these things and used the former to power the latter.

Comment: @senshin Well ok, this seems pretty right :D could you post it as an answer so I can accept it and this one is closed :D

Comment: I've now found something out: 1. the producers of this anime worked together on "Fate/Zero  so this name was used in this anime too. and 2. The ".Zero" could reffer to the types of fighting of the protagonists which don't use Aldnoah (so "Zero"). But nevertheless they have a Aldnoah-powered airship and so I don't think that's the answer :D

Comment: @JetStream I'm not going to post that as an answer; there's still a fair bit of stuff I haven't read (like Twin Gemini) that could answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Aldnoah refers to the power/energy itself. "Aldnoah.Zero" or "Aldnoah Zero" is never named or stated in-series. It could just be meant as a cool title, but I like to imagine it refers to the Terrans who fight without Aldnoah or other Versian weapons/technology. ;)